# Introduction to the black holes and mass positive theorem in a geometric point of view

Tags: black-holes, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, education

I'm a math student with no physics background who want understand more about black holes and mass positive theorem in order to understand better the motivations of the Inverse Mean Curvature Flow (my main goal of study) and how to see the evolution of manifolds by this flow geometrically. I want to study these topics by myself, but the resources that I found is more formal than intuitive, i.e., an explanation of the definitions with pictures like on pages $17$ to $21$ in [this](http://www.math.miami.edu/~galloway/evans.pdf) presentation by Greg Galloway, so I would like to references to start to selfstudy black holes and mass positive theorem in such way a student without physics background, but with math background be able to understand the theory of black holes and mass positive theorem alone.